# How to compile with MINGW64 on Windows ？

Tags: c, windows, build, mingw-w64, msys2

I wanted to use the gettext api to parse the po file and compile a gettext by hand, but I ran into some problems during the compilation process:

```
Making all in adhoc-tests
make[5]: Enter directory“/home/test/gettext-tools-windows/build/compile/gettext-0.22.3/libtextstyle/adhoc-tests”
  CC       hello.o
  CCLD     hello.exe
libtool: warning: library '/home/test/gettext-tools-windows/build/stage/usr/local/lib/libiconv.la' was moved.
libtool: warning: library '/home/test/gettext-tools-windows/build/stage/usr/local/lib/libiconv.la' was moved.
C:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: hello.o:hello.c:(.text.startup+0x98): undefined reference to `__imp_color_test_mode'
C:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: hello.o:hello.c:(.text.startup+0xa8): undefined reference to `__imp_color_mode'
C:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: hello.o:hello.c:(.text.startup+0xcc): undefined reference to `__imp_style_file_name'
C:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: hello.o:hello.c:(.text.startup+0x1c1): undefined reference to `__imp_style_file_name'
C:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: hello.o:hello.c:(.text.startup+0x21a): undefined reference to `__imp_style_file_name'
C:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: hello.o:hello.c:(.text.startup+0x250): undefined reference to `__imp_style_file_name'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [Makefile:1777：hello.exe] Error 1
make[5]: Leave directory“/home/test/gettext-tools-windows/build/compile/gettext-0.22.3/libtextstyle/adhoc-tests”
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1992：all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leave directory“/home/test/gettext-tools-windows/build/compile/gettext-0.22.3/libtextstyle”
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1920：all] Error 2
make[3]: Leave directory“/home/test/gettext-tools-windows/build/compile/gettext-0.22.3/libtextstyle”
make[2]: *** [Makefile:406：all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leave directory“/home/test/gettext-tools-windows/build/compile/gettext-0.22.3”
make[1]: *** [Makefile:362：all] Error 2
make[1]: Leave directory“/home/test/gettext-tools-windows/build/compile/gettext-0.22.3”
make: *** [Makefile:100：/home/test/gettext-tools-windows/build/compile/GETTEXT.built] Error 2
```

Comment: Why are you compiling gettext by hand, when there's a prebuilt package? Also, is this the `libtool` package? You should be using `mingw-w64-x86_64-libtool` instead.

Comment: With msys2 you can find packages by `pacman -Ss gettext`

Comment: Since I want to add this dependency to the project, I can just compile and bundle it without any extra action

Comment: Did installing the correct libtool change anything?

Comment: After I reinstall MSYS2, the compilation can be passed. I think it must be the compilation environment problem. What software conflicts are there